# How to make entire Jtable invisible in Swing?

Tags: swing, jtable, invisible

I have two tables in Single Jframe. I want to hide one table and show the other one and again hide the previous one and set visible the other one.
I have tried `upload.jTable1.setVisible(false);` but its is not Working. Any input?

Comment: try setting visibility of JScrollpane that contains jtable

Comment: any code, preferably a SSCCE? (Or in other words: something wrong with the code you are not showing ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your table in a JPanel and use for the panel [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)